# celery application hanging for minutes before continuing

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery

I have an app consisting of celery workers, an orchestrating main celery app, and dockerized rabbitmq and redis as broker and backend. All services run on the same machine. The workers as well as the orchestrating main celery app are all running as system services, monitored by systemd.

The app runs a loop that dispatches over 20k messages (chunked tasks) each iteration (but never starting a task that is already running).

Here's a snippet of the code:

```py
    chunk_args = (
        (asset, tc, pc) for tc, pc in itertools.product(time_chunks, pos_chunks)
    )

    pipe = func.chunks(chunk_args, settings.NUM_PROCESSES).group()

    logger.warn("Sending pipe")
    val = pipe.apply_async()
    logger.warn(f"Pipe sent {val}")

    return val
```

Every now and then, however, the orchestrating process hangs and I don't know why. It'll hang for 1-2 minutes between seeing "Sending pipe" and "Pipe sent", but sometimes also after "Pipe sent". (Checking with `journalctl -f -xu service`.

Using `docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl list_queues` I can see that the queue is empty while this happens, and `htop` doesn't show any processes that are particularly busy, and RAM consumption seems to stay below 30 GB.

I have run a profiler (py-spy) on my main process to verify if it's hanging on this or another function call, but it literally isn't showing anything - I assume that means that the thread is idle or sleeping (since py-spy does not report idle).

`docker logs rabbitmq` also doesn't show anything special.

The machine is powerful with 128GB of RAM and a Ryzen 5 with 32 cores. It has a 80 TB hardware RAID1 cluster formatted as btrfs, as well as 2 250 GB SSDs forming a software RAID1 cluster (60 GB swap; 170 GB root partition).

What other tools do I have to inspect what's going on? And what might be going on? Could it be that systemd suspends busy processes from time to time?

Comment: What is the concurrency type (prefork, thread, gevent, eventlet, solo) ?

Comment: @DejanLekic it's preforking I think

Comment: @DejanLekic I have added some system information in case that has any influence.